# Improving Vim omni completion

Tags: vim, omnicomplete, omnicppcomplete

How can I add help information or improve omni completion in Vim?
For example, in a CSS file, when you type `font`, omni completion could show the expected values: `font-style font-variant font-weight font-size/line-height font-family`

Comment: "*For example, in a CSS file, when you type 'font', omni completion could show the expected values*" Well, actually it shows. Type font and press CTRL-X CTRL-O

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to do that with omni completion, but you could use the [snipmate](https://github.com/vim-scripts/snipMate) plugin (maybe with [these packaged snippets](https://github.com/vim-scripts/snipmate-snippets)) and add this snippet for css files :

```
font: ${1:font-style} ${2:font-variant} ${3:font-weight} ${4:font-size/line-height} ${5:font-family}
```

So that you can type:

```
font<tab>italic<tab><backspace><tab>normal<tab>12px<tab>sans-serif;
```

Answer (score -2):

For css/html you could try Zen Coding
http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/

Comment: A more appropriate link would have been http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2981